# Vue watch does not trigger when changing the data value to the same value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a UNO clone, I used a watcher to execute code on every turn start:

```js
  watch: {
    // on turn change
    async turnId(val) {
      const isUserTurn = val === 0;

      if (isUserTurn) {
        // reset has drawed flag
        // this.hasDrawed = false;
      } else {
        await setTimeout(() => this.playAI(), 1000);
      }
    },
  },
```

when it's not the user's turn this code runs:

```js
await setTimeout(() => this.playAI(), 1000);
```

the playAI method is:

```js
    playAI() {
      // get the card and play it
      this.play(card)
    },
```

```js
    play(card) {
      // play the card (delete from hand and put on piletop)

      this.nextTurn();

      if (card.value === '+4') {
        this.currentPlayer.hand.push(...this.draw(4));
        this.nextTurn();
      } else if (card.value === '+2') {
        this.currentPlayer.hand.push(...this.draw(2));
        this.nextTurn();
      } else if (card.value === 'skip') {
        this.nextTurn();
      }
    },
```

```js
    nextTurn() {
      // if the turn id is greater than the total number of players then back it up
      if (this.turnId === this.playersNumber - 1) this.turnId = 0;
      else this.turnId += 1;
    },
```

The problem is that when the AI plays a card like skip, it plays the card (skip), it runs next turn method twice (turnId + 2) but the watcher on turnId doesn't run the second time so the AI stops playing.

- This bug happens only on AI turn and not user's so I think the error comes from the watcher
- I'm testing it with only two players so when the AI plays a card like skip the turn comes back to him (it changes but it comes back at the same value as before) so this might be the error since when the method stops running the turnId value is the same as before the function call

If that's the error how can I force the watcher to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this problem by changing the play method:

```js
  play(card) {

    if (card.value === 'reverse') { // if card is reverse
      this.isReversed = !this.isReversed; // inverse reversed flag
    } else if (card.value === 'skip') { // if card is skip
      this.skipTurn = true; // set skip flag
    } else if (card.value === '+2') { // if card is +2
      this.nextPlayer.hand.push(...this.draw(2)); // nextPlayer draws 2
      this.nextPlayer.hand.sort(this.sortHandler); // sort the hand of the player who draws
      this.skipTurn = true; // set skip flag
    } else if (card.value === '+4') { // if card is +4
      this.nextPlayer.hand.push(...this.draw(4)); // nextPlayer draws 4
      this.nextPlayer.hand.sort(this.sortHandler); // sort the hand of the player who draws
      this.skipTurn = true; // set skip flag
    }

    // next turn
    this.nextTurn();
  }
```

- I created nextPlayer computed that does the same thing as currentPlayer but on the next one
- I also created a flag that checks if the next player has to skip the turn and checked it in the watcher:

```js
  turnId(turn) {
    if (this.skipTurn) {
      this.skipTurn = false;
      this.nextTurn();
      return;
    }

    if (turn !== 0) { // if it's bot's turn
      this.playAI();
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Watcher is executed only once in an event loop, you should make the second call in async

---

append

example:

```
    play(card) {
      // play the card (delete from hand and put on piletop)

      this.nextTurn();
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (card.value === '+4') {
          this.currentPlayer.hand.push(...this.draw(4));
          this.nextTurn();
        } else if (card.value === '+2') {
          this.currentPlayer.hand.push(...this.draw(2));
          this.nextTurn();
        } else if (card.value === 'skip') {
          this.nextTurn();
        }
      }, 0)
    }
```

This way the watcher will execute twice, but it will lead to unintended results and you will need to consider how to adjust

Comment: how can I do that?